# Can you make that thats code run in python 2.7 from 3.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

i have code that runs in python 3.5 but i need it for python 2.7. Because on the school system runs only 2.7 and i can only write 3.5. The programm calculate square roots with the herron principle. sorry for my bad English

```
#y = number from that you want the square root 
#a = first side of the square
#b = second side of the square
#m = middle of both numbers
#x = a*b/m
#i = number of Iteration
#c = number of maked Iterations
import math

c = 0
m = 0
x = 0

y = int(input("Number from that you want the square root(only numbers without a comma):"))
i = int(input("Number of Iterationen: "))


a = y/2
b = 2

print("first side of the square",a)
print("second side of the square", b)


while i > 0:
    m = (a+b)/2
    x = (a*b)/m
    a = m
    b = x
    print("first side of square after",c,"Iterations is",a)
    print("second side of square after",c,"Iterations is",b)
    i = i-1
    c = c+1

print("Final",a)

print("calculate per command",math.sqrt(y))
```

Comment: That program *already* runs in 2.7. What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: It is possible to write code that runs on both Python 2.7 and Python 3.5.  One way is to use the `six` library and a couple of `__future__` imports.

Comment: I think `from __future__ import division, print_function` or changing your `(a+b)/2` to `(a+b)/2.` and `a = y/2` to `a = y/2.` should be enough.

Comment: @Robᵩ The program kind of runs in Python 2.7.  The `input()` calls will do something unexpected, since they will evaluate all Python code you enter.  And the print statements will print tuples in Python 2, which is also not intended.

Comment: @MSeifert In addition, `from __future__ import print_function` is needed, and some logic to set `input = raw_input` when Python 2 is detected.

Comment: @SvenMarnach well `int(input())` should behave quite similar between py2 and 3 and I thought I already edited the `print` import.

Comment: @MSeifert No, `int(input())` will execute any Python expression you enter in Python 2, while it will only accept integers in Python 3.  And I hadn't seen your edit when I wrote the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to the top of your program:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
```

Then it will run under 2.7 and give you the same answers as if you were running 3.5.

"However, if you enter a Python expression instead of a number, it will be executed in Python 2, whereas you will get an error in Python 3, since input() has different meanings in Python 2 and 3." – [Sven Marnac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279627/sven-marnach)

Comment: However, if you enter a Python expression instead of a number, it will be executed in Python 2, whereas you will get an error in Python 3, since `input()` has different meanings in Python 2 and 3.

Comment: @SvenMarnach - True. I couldn't find the right words to express that, so I'll steal yours.

Answer (score 2):

@Rob is definetly right about the `from __future__ import division, print_function` line.

But if you also want to have the equivalent `input` function you could use:

```
try:
    input = raw_input  # Py2
except NameError:
    pass               # Py3
```

or with [`six`](https://pythonhosted.org/six/#module-six.moves):

```
from six.moves import input
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rob solution or you could just change every `print()` into `print` (with a space)

e.g. Change:

```
print("calculate per command",math.sqrt(y))
```

Into:

```
print "calculate per command",math.sqrt(y)
```

You should change the `input` function into `raw_input`. 
(although it will still work fine, just won't thorw all the errors: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input)